# CUDA Build Error with CUDA 5.5.targets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, msbuild

I'm a student trying to add a CUDA project in a exsisting C++ project.

I installed the Toolkit and cheked it worked fine on my computer.

Basic settings such as include directory and Library Directory Setting were all done.

However, when I am trying to build the whole project, the error occurs with CUDA 5.5.target.

The error code is written below:

**1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.5.targets(592,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I\include -I.\Inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -DFDTDCOREWIN32_EXPORTS -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_ATL_STATIC_REGISTRY -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o x64\Debug\FDTD_CU.cu.obj "C:\Users\mpich2\Desktop\FDTD_CU.cu"" exited with code 2.**

Anybody help me out?

ps. My CUDA Toolkit version is 5.5 and i am using Windows 7 with 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the only error or do you have additional errors you are not showing?

Comment: To add to what Jack said, if this is the only indication of a problem that you can see in the Visual studio console window at the bottom, then you need to change your visual studio settings to show all compile output.   You should be able to see the actual results of the `nvcc` output (which will be more descriptive) rather than just the fact that MSVS saw that `nvcc` returned an error.  If not, your MSVS settings are not set to the full output/verbose mode.

Comment: 1>C:/Users/mpich2/Desktop/MPI_130331/FDTDCoreWin32/FDTD_CU.cu(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cutil_inline.h': No such file or directory



It is the error before i got the error above.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I guess you'll have to figure out what `cutil_inline.h` is, and see what is the best way for you to provide it or else eliminate it. Search for `CUDA cutil` in the upper right hand corner of this page, and you'll get many useful ideas.

Comment: Thank you all. As far as i noticed. NVIDIA doesn't support 'cutil_inline.h' in 5.5 anymore. Instead of "cutil_inline.h", i was able to include "help_cuda.h".